# How to interpolate 100 values into the every two values?

Tags: python, interpolation

I want to interpolate 100 values into the  every two values(0.05 seconds,as the following 'data.csv'), and  should remain  the following data still unchanged.

```
 time         data
2013-02-12T02:58:00.047803  -1286
2013-02-12T02:58:00.097803  -1271
2013-02-12T02:58:00.147803  -1297
2013-02-12T02:58:00.197803  -1290
2013-02-12T02:58:00.247803  -1314
......
```

and some code is:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import interpolate
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('aa.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
xnew=np.linspace(df["time"],len(df["data"]),60)
f=interpolate.interp1d(df["time"],df["data"],kind="cubic")

ynew=f(xnew)
pl.plot(xnew,ynew,label="cubic", marker='.' )
pl.show()
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why do you want "the data still unchanged"? you want to see them on the plot? The easiest thing is to completely forget properly formatted time values, and instead use some integers to refer to time

Comment: the orign data can't be changed .  such as :2013-02-12T02:58:00.047803  -1286
2013-02-12T02:58:00.097803  -1271

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that you need to properly format your time values, as pandas is loading them as strings, for example you could transform them into seconds.

Then, you are using `np.linspace` function in a wrong way. How many points do you want to calculate?

Here is an example of code:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import interpolate
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
import dateutil
import datetime

time2seconds = lambda x:(dateutil.parser.parse(x)-datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()
df = pd.read_csv('aa.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
df["time"] = map(time2seconds, df["time"])
xnew = np.linspace(start=min(df["time"]), stop=max(df["time"]), num=len(df["time"])*4)
f = interpolate.interp1d(df["time"], df["data"], kind="cubic")
ynew = f(xnew)
pl.plot(xnew, ynew, label="cubic", marker='.' )
pl.show()
```

**- Edit -** 
for timestamps you probably want to use pd.to_datetime